# Equal Rectangles animate differently?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct GrowView: View {
    var size:CGFloat = 400
    @State var scale:CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(height: 300 * scale)
                .animation(.default)
            if true {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(height: 400 * scale)
                    .animation(.default)
            }

        }.onAppear {
            self.scale = 1
        }.frame( maxHeight: 500, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}

struct GrowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GrowView()
    }
}
```

Without the `if` block, the second `Rectangle` animates from bottom to top. When it is inside the `If` block however, it appears to draw from the top to bottom. What's going on?

Comment: fascinating.... ;)

Comment: If you wrap the state change it works the same way in both cases:  `onAppear { withAnimation  { self.scale = 1 } }`. Both rectangles animate from the bottom.

Comment: @Abizern it worked! Sadly, when I moved on to the next phase of my plan (delaying the second one, it stopped :() All I did was add `.animation(Animation.default.delay(1.0))` to the second rectangle and now it draws from the top again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a way to make them animate into one direction (instead of thinking about *why* and *how could*) then here is a solution

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(height: 300 * scale)
//                .animation(.default)   // XX remove !!
            if true {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(height: 400 * scale)
//                    .animation(.default) // XX remove !!
            }

        }
        .animation(.default)       // << put animation here !!!
        .onAppear {
            self.scale = 1
        }.frame( maxHeight: 500, alignment: .bottom)
    }
```

Update: solution for conditional second rectangle with delay

```
struct GrowView: View {
    var size:CGFloat = 400
    @State var scale:CGFloat = 0
    @State var showSecond = true

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(height: 300 * scale)
                .animation(.default)
            VStack {
                if showSecond {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(height: 400 * scale)
                }
            }
            .animation(Animation.default.delay(0.5))
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.scale = 1
        }.frame(maxHeight: 500, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work. Sadly, I excluded the next phase of my master plan: Have the second rectangle start animating slightly after the first.

Comment: @speg, then why do you need that condition?

Comment: If the condition is true: draw the second rectangle after a delay. The second rectangle doesn't always exist.

Comment: it worked! Thanks. Any insight as to why? Throwing `VStack`s around feels superfluous.